# How to query git log for Co-Authored-By

Tags: git

If I want to find commits authored by Joe Blo, easy:

```
git log --author=joe.blo@x.com
```

But what if the commit was created as follows:

```
git commit -m "Our awesome code changes.
>
>
Co-authored-by: Joe Blo <joe.blo@x.com>
Co-authored-by: Henry Chilinsky <henry@example.com>"
```

As described here: https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors

Above, Joe has been credited as a co-author, but my original `--author=joe.blo@x.com` query won't find the this commit. How can I find commits where Joe is a co-author?

EDIT: Command line solution preferred, but bonus points for third party tools that can handle this:  `tig`, `github`, `tower`, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [trailer options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emtrailersoptionsem), because `Co-authored-by` is a trailer in a commit message.

```
git log --format="%h %s %(trailers:key=Co-authored-by)"
```

But you will need to grep the result for Joe.
`valueonly` would filter on the value (for instance `Joe`), but irrespective of the key (`Co-authored-by`)

Answer (score 4):

I initially tried this:

```
git log --format="%h %(trailers:key=Co-authored-by)" | grep="Joe Blo <joe.blo@x.com>"
```

But for large repos (~1.5mio commits) it doesn't perform very well.

Using built-in `--grep` is faster:

```
git log --grep="Co-authored-by: Joe Blo <joe.blo@x.com>"
```

or

```
git log --format="%h %(trailers:key=Co-authored-by)" --grep="Joe Blo <joe.blo@x.com>"
```

The latter two perform equally faster.

Comment: Nice. Adding --grep should help indeed.

Comment: Thanks. `git log --pretty="%C(cyan)%ad %<(7,trunc)%aN %C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s %(trailers:key=Co-authored-by)" --date-order --graph --date=iso --grep="Matt"` was helpful for me. I still don't know how to search GitHub in this way, but at least now I can do this locally. I combined your answer with https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584751/470749 https://github.blog/2018-01-29-commit-together-with-co-authors/