# How to get commits by multiple authors?

Tags: git

I can get commits for one author like:

```
git log <branch_1>..<branch_2> --author=John
git log <branch_1>..<branch_2> --author=Mike
```

But how can I get commits for both `John, Mike` at the same time?

Comment: I think you can have multiple `--author` arguments in a single `git log` run

Comment: You definitely can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the `--author` twice:

```sh
git log -i <branch_1>..<branch_2> --author=john --author=mike
```

Or, since `--author` accepts regex, you can do:

```sh
git log --author='\(John\)\|\(Mike\)'
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for co-author trailers: https://github.blog/2018-01-29-commit-together-with-co-authors/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263083/how-to-query-git-log-for-co-authored-by#comment135971882_75673377 is what I needed.