# How to truncate and pad author in `git log` output?

Tags: git

I have this command whose output is nearly what I want:

`alias gitlog="git log --pretty='%C(cyan)%ad %an %C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s' --date-order --graph --date=iso"`

Output:

[image: git log output screenshot]

```
* 2022-08-31 10:47:07 -0400 John Doe 0732ee2  eslint-disable react/prop-types for certain files until we clean them up
* 2022-08-31 10:45:21 -0400 John Doe 02b278c  eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope for certain files until we clean them up
* 2022-08-31 11:34:54 +0100 Susan Johnson f5bbc9f  Fixing circular dependency
```

But as you can see, authors' names are different lengths, so the "columns" get misaligned.

I'd like to be able to choose a number of characters (such as 7) and edit my command such that the author "column" is exactly that width (truncated as necessary and padded with spaces as necessary).

Does git log formatting support this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `%<(7,trunc)%aN` is what I was hoping for!

`git log --pretty='%C(cyan)%ad %<(7,trunc)%aN %C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s' --date-order --graph --date=iso`

[image: git log screenshot]

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831280/470749